# How to obtain mp3 stream as float array in java

Tags: java, mp3

I have been using mp3spi, tritonus and JLayer to process mp3 files. I am stuck up at one point where I need mp3 input stream / mp3 audio signal as **floating point array**. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a floating point array?

Comment: Include some sample code from the section you are having trouble with.

Comment: I need floating point array of audio signal to apply FFT and some other formulas on it. 
I already have C++ code which uses LAME for this purpose. I am looking for pure Java equivalent of LAME which does not depend on any dll or so.

Comment: please find the sample code :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138526/getting-mp3-audio-signal-as-array-in-java

Comment: If you want a message to reach Perception or myself, you need to reply to one of our answers (not possible, in this case), or add @name before the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using or sub-classing [`java.io.DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)? Perhaps the `readFloat()` method is what you are looking for.

Comment: No. More details available in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138526/getting-mp3-audio-signal-as-array-in-java